# How to set text color to all radio buttons in Java?

Tags: android

I have created programmatically, 5 radio groups with 4 radio buttons each. Every radio button represents an answer to a question. When someone checks the correct answer, i want to toast a message (that works fine) and than, if someone press the button, i want to set all the correct answers the color green. With this code, when i press the button, a single answer is turned on green, the correct answer from the last radio group. I want all the correct answers from all radio groups to turn on green, when i press the button. Where am i wrong?
Here is my code:

```
RadioGroup[] radioGroup;
RadioButton[] answer;
RadioButton checkedRadioButton;

    radioGroup = new RadioGroup[5];
    answer = new RadioButton[4];
    int i = 0;
    for (Question qn : questions) {
        radioGroup[i] = new RadioGroup(this);
        int j = 0;
        for (Answer an : answers) {
            if (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) {
                answer[j] = new RadioButton(this);
                radioGroup[i].addView(answer[j]);

                answer[j].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        checkedRadioButton = ((RadioButton) v);
                        int CorrectAnswer = Integer.parseInt(checkedRadioButton.getTag().toString());
                        if (checkedRadioButton.isChecked() & CorrectAnswer == 1) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct answer checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
                j++;
            }
        }
        linearLayout.addView(radioGroup[i]);
        i++;
    }

    finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkedRadioButton.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
            for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < answer.length; j++) {
                    radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setEnabled(false);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue after reviewing your code is that you have all of your buttons having the same ID and you are only taking the ID of the selected button regardless of whether or not it is correct. What I did was I added an array list that holds the correct rads and then sets them green from there :).

```
    for (Answer an : answers) {
            if (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) {
                answer[j] = new RadioButton(this);
                answer[j].setText(an.getAnswer());
                answer[j].setId(j + 100);
                answer[j].setTag(String.valueOf(an.getCorrect_answer()));
                if(answer[j].getTag().toString().equals("1")){
                    correctAnswerRadios.add(answer[j]);
                }
                radioGroup[i].addView(answer[j]);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much! Best answer of all.